Checker color in a Node is not changing
I've been experimenting with controlling Blender material via script and I've run into some rather peculiar issue.
In the material I have a checker texture with color input. I want to change the color. I assume it works the same way any other color input works, using RGBA order. So I created a variable with a random number generated and assign it to the color input. In the terminal it seems to be changed, but the color stays the same. I wonder if there is something I've missed.
furnimat_nodes = the_material2.node_tree.nodes
furnimat_1stcolor = furnimat_nodes["TestCheckerTest"].inputs[1]

red = random.random()
green = random.random()
blue = random.random()
color = (red, green, blue, 1.0)

furnimat_1stcolor = color
print(furnimat_1stcolor)


Hello, you want to use furnimat_1stcolor.default_value = color

Oh thanks, works now! Interestingly I had the defaul_value in the furnimat_1stcolor variable like furnimat_1stcolor = furnimat_nodes["FirstColor"].inputs[1].default_value but that doesn't work

Some basic python tutorials might help you.
So, when you do furnimat_1stcolor = furnimat_nodes["TestCheckerTest"].inputs[1], you're assigning a var to point to the input.
And when you do furnimat_1stcolor = color, you're assgining a var again. You're definitely not changing anything in the node.
You need one of these two options:

furnimat_nodes["TestCheckerTest"].inputs[1].default_value = color
furnimat_1stcolor.default_value = color

